# Check if a Swing form does not contain empty fields

Tags: java, swing

I want to determine if a form containing: JTextField, JDatePicker, JComboBox, JSpinner, does not contain empty fields.
I have several forms with different fields that I would like to be evaluated with a common method without managing the order of the fields to work with any sequence of fields.

My purpose would be to create a method like:

```
if method (field1, field2, field3) {
...
}
if method (field4, field5) {
...
}
```

I don't want to do multiple methods for multiple forms.

Comment: Create an ArrayList of components you want to validate. Then you iterate through the ArrayList checking if each component. When you find an empty component you return false.

Comment: Could you write your own version of the code? Each component has its own version of the check.

Comment: @user192837 Yes, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69598115/261156); you'll find that you can reuse verifiers for common field types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Polymorphism should be used.

For that you'll need an abstract verifier. [*Validating Input*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#inputVerification) shows how to write an [`InputVerifier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/InputVerifier.html) for each type of field in each of your forms. Then each concrete `InputVerifier` will have a `verify()` that you can invoke on each `JComponent` in the form. When it's time to verify the form, given a `List<JComponent> list`,  you can verify the entire form like this:

```
boolean b = true;
for (JComponent field : list) {
    b &= field.getInputVerifier().verify(field);
}
b &= someOtherFormLevelPredicate;
…
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do as @camickr mentioned in a comment above:

> Create an ArrayList of components you want to validate. Then you iterate through the ArrayList checking if each component. When you find an empty component you return false.

And you could check for the type of field they are and then check if they are empty / not selected.

```
private boolean isFormValid(List<JComponent> components) {
    for (int i = 0; i < components.size(); i++) {
        if (components.get(i) instanceof JTextField) {
            if (components.get(i).getText().isEmpty()) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        if (components.get(i) instanceof JComboBox) {
            if (components.get(i).getSelectedItem() == null) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        // Add checks for other components you want to check here
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I too had thought of a solution with instanceof but at the implementation level using an instanceof chain is a problem.  Polymorphism should be used.

Comment: I think this is the right idea. Using `InputVerifier` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69598115/261156) is one way to use polymorphism.